Flutter How to save excel file to download folder?
Hi everyone I'm trying to save an Excel file into the public Download folder on my phone storage and the user can find it ay anytime I tried this code
    var fileBytes = excel.save();
    var directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String directoryPath = directory!.path;
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();

but it saves the file at
"/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.stepbystep.msrofaty/files" and I can't find that file on my device
and I tried to use this code
     final dir = Directory("storage/emulated/0/Download");
     directoryPath = dir.path;

but I got an error
FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = ‘storage/emulated/0/Download’ (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)

that's my manifest file
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

var status = await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();

if (status.isGranted) 

I do my complete code at saving the file, can anyone help me please?
